# Tensorflow: Avoid Downloading Inception V3 for Every Run

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow

For a somewhat old machine learning project (TensorFlow 1.4) that I'm reviving, the Inception V3 model is used (`demo.py`):

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3

model = InceptionV3()
```

Since the older versions do not work properly together with my Python setup on Arch Linux, I decided to run the code in a Docker container. The image is built as follows (`Dockerfile`):

```
FROM python:3.5-stretch

RUN pip install tensorflow==1.4.0

ENV WORKDIR=/usr/src/app
WORKDIR $WORKDIR
COPY demo.py $WORKDIR

CMD ["python", "demo.py"]
```

I build the image and run the container as follows:

```
$ docker build . -t inception_v3
$ docker run inception_v3
```

When I run the container, a log entry appears after a couple of seconds:

```
Downloading data from https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/releases/download/v0.5/inception_v3_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5
```

After roughly 30 seconds, the program goes on (with an error message that isn't of interest for the moment...).

My question: Is it possible to avoid that download and to provide the file through another mechanism? I can download it from GitHub once, but I don't know how to provide the file in the Python code.

The time to download the file every time is annoying; and what, if the file will no longer be on GitHub all of a sudden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you need to put the file inside `~/.keras/models` and Keras will pick it up automatically.

Comment: Thanks! I my case, it needs to be `/root/.keras/models`. However, I probably should introduce a proper user to run the code.